# postgreSQL - psql \i : how to execute script in a given path

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgreSQL and I have a simple question:

I'm trying to create a simple script that creates a DB so I can later call it like this:

```
psql -f createDB.sql
```

I want the script to call other scripts (separate ones for creating tables, adding constraints, functions etc), like this:

```
\i script1.sql
\i script2.sql
```

It works fine provided that createDB.sql is in the **same dir**.

But if I move script2 to a directory under the one with createDB, and modify the createDB so it looks like this:

```
\i script1.sql
\i somedir\script2.sql
```

I get an error:

> psql:createDB.sql:2: somedir: Permission denied

I'm using Postgres Plus 8.3 for windows, default postgres user.

**EDIT:**

Silly me, unix slashes solved the problem.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Postgres started on Linux/Unix.  I suspect that reversing the slash with fix it.

```
\i somedir/script2.sql
```

If you need to fully qualify something

```
\i c:/somedir/script2.sql
```

If that doesn't fix it, my next guess would be you need to escape the backslash.

```
\i somedir\\script2.sql
```

Comment: Reversing the slashes was sufficient, escapes weren't necessary.

Comment: Of note is that forward slashes are perfectly valid in Windows and natively supported. So you can use forward slashes almost everywhere in Windows (with the exception of poorly written applications). Since the backslash is often used as an escape character, its behavior will be inconsistent between applications and even uses inside a single application.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using Unix style slashes (/ instead of \)?

\ is often an escape or command character, and may be the source of confusion.   I have never had issues with this, but I also do not have Windows, so I cannot test it.

Additionally, the permissions may be based on the user running psql, or maybe the user executing the postmaster service, check that both have read to that file in that directory.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, I work myself to do so

```
\i 'somedir\\script2.sql'
```

Answer (score 0):

i did try this and its working in windows machine to run a sql file on a specific schema.

> psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U username -d databasename -v schema=schemaname < e:\Table.sql