# How to import external sql scripts from a sql script in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, include, plpgsql

I was wondering if it is possible/how to `include` one .sql file in another .sql file, as is done in other programming languages like C or Java?

I am asking because I wanted to organize my sql scripts into support library files and application scripts, and so on. I searched around, and solutions seem to be about loading .sql files from the psql client (see e.g. [postgreSQL - psql \i : how to execute script in a given path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129445/)). What I am interested in is to load a library .sql script from inside a sql script.

P.S. I am using PL/pgSQL (PostgreSQL 9.3).

Comment: Make them stored procedures.

Comment: Provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to clarify your objective. Show the code you are trying the nest, even if it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer [It is possible to reference another SQL file from SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33120043/4934640), on PostgreSQL, you can include another SQL's files just using the `\i` syntax. I just tested and is working good on PostgreSQL 9.6:

```
\i other_script.sql
SELECT * FROM table_1;
SELECT * FROM table_2;
```