# How to run postgres sql script from another script?

Tags: postgresql

I have a bunch of SQL scripts that create tables in the database. Each table is located in a separate file so that editing them is much easier.

I wanted to prepare a single SQL script that will create the full schema, create tables, insert test data and generate sequences for the tables.

I was able to do such thing for oracle database but I am having problems with postgres.
The thing is - I do not know how to run the table creating script from another script.

In oracle I do it using the following syntax:

```
@@'path of the script related to the path of the currently running sql file'
```

And everything works like a charm.

In postgres I was trying to search for something alike and found this:

```
\ir 'relative path to the file'
```

Unfortunately when I run my main script I get the message:

```
No such file or directory.
```

The example call is here:

```
\ir './tables/map_user_groups.sql'
```

I use Postgres 9.3. I tried to run the script using psql:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -d postgres < "path to my main sql file"
```

The file executes fine except for the calling of those other scripts.

Does anybody know how to solve the problem ?

If something in the question is unclear - just let me know :)

Comment: In which operating system are you attempting to accomplish this?

Comment: `psql -U postgres -h localhost -d postgres < "path to my main sql file"` : from psql's perspective the main_sql file is just stdin. stdin has no "filename"; use `-f filename` to submit a file **with** a name.

Comment: Thank you @wildplasser, that was it :) rchang I do it on Windows 7 Professional

Comment: @wildplasser Might I suggest you post this as an answer?  It helped me just now.

Comment: The problem is: for unix people this solution is so trivial that is is embarassing to post as an answer...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Based on the answer [It is possible to reference another SQL file from SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33120043/4934640), on PostgreSQL, you can include another SQL's files just using the `\i` syntax. I just tested and is working good on PostgreSQL 9.6:

```
\i other_script.sql
SELECT * FROM table_1;
SELECT * FROM table_2;
```

By the @wildplasser comment:

> > ```
> > psql -U postgres -h localhost -d postgres < "path to my main sql file"
> > ```
> >
> > From psql's perspective the `main_sql` file is just stdin, and stdin has no "filename". Use `-f filename` to submit a file with a name:
> >
> > ```
> > psql -U postgres -h localhost -d postgres -f filename.sql
> > ```

> How to run postgres sql script from another script?

Seems the same question as: [How to import external sql scripts from a sql script in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27652408/4934640)

Comment: is there a way to do it from PgAdmin4 or only if I am running it from the console?