# It is possible to reference another SQL file from SQL script

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Basically I want to execute an SQL file from an SQL file in Postgres.

Similar question for mysql: [is it possible to call a sql script from a stored procedure in another sql script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547915/is-it-possible-to-call-a-sql-script-from-a-stored-procedure-in-another-sql-scrip)

Why?

Because I have 2 data files in a project and I want to have one line that can be commented/un-commented that loads the second file.

**Clarification:**
I want to call B.SQL from A.SQL

**Clarification2:**
This is for a Spring Project that uses hibernate to create the database from the initial SQL file (A.SQL).

On further reflection it seems I may have to handle this from java/string/hibernate.

**Below is the configuration file:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.data=classpath:db/migration/postgres/data.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: How do you want to execute the sql file? with psql?

Comment: @Tommaso Di Bucchianico I want to call one sql file from another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate is just:

1. reading all your SQL files line per line
2. strip any comment (lines starting with `--`, `//` or `/*`)
3. removes any `;` at the end
4. executes the result as a single statement

(see [`SchemaExport.importScript`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.java) and [`SingleLineSqlCommandExtractor`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SingleLineSqlCommandExtractor.java))

There is no support for an include here.

What you can do:

- Define your own `ImportSqlCommandExtractor` which knows how to include a file - you can set that extractor with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=(fully qualified class name)`
- Define your optional file as additional import file with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=prefix.sql,optional.sql,postfix.sql`, you can either add and remove the file reference as you like, or you can even exclude the file from your artifact - a missing file will only create a debug message.
- Create an `Integrator` which sets the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property dynamically - depending on some environment property

Answer (score 9):

Import of other files is not supported in Sql, but if you execute the script with [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html) can you use the `\i` syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1;
\i other_script.sql
SELECT * FROM table_2;
```

This will probably not work if you execute the sql with other clients than `psql`.

Comment: Yeah, you still don't say how do you want to execute the script

Comment: It's run through hibernate in a Java Spring Project. Your right, I didn't. I think that maybe I need to handle this in hibernate/java.