# Postgres PSQL Import file from certain location

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.4

I have my dump file of DB Dump via psql, I want to import it to my windows Postgres via PSQL from a certain location. However when I try the following:

```
postgres-# psql cds < C:\Users\user\Desktop\cds_db.bak
```

I get the  following error:

```
Invalid command \Users. Try \? for help.
```

I also tried the following:

```
 postgres-# psql cds < cds_db.bak
```

But it was quiet, nothing happened.

The file is located on my desktop, how can I import the file?

Comment: What are you typing your commands into?

Comment: Perhaps this will help [psql \i : how to execute script in a given path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129445/postgresql-psql-i-how-to-execute-script-in-a-given-path#129496).  See also [psql — PostgreSQL interactive terminal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) search for "\i"

Comment: When you see the `postgres-#` prompt you already started the command line tool `psql` - and `psql` is not a SQL statement you can use inside `psql`. Just use the `\i` command that is specific to `psql`